# How do you display a 2D numpy array in glade-3 ?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gtk, glade

I'm making live video GUI using Python and Glade-3, but I'm finding it hard to convert the Numpy array that I have into something that can be displayed in Glade. The images are in black and white with just a single value giving the brightness of each pixel. I would like to be able to draw over the images in the GUI so I don't know whether there is a specific format I should use (bitmap/pixmap etc) ?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i decided to create a buffer for the pixels using:

self.pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,0,8,1280,1024)

I then set the image from the pixel buffer:

self.liveImage.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)

Answer (score 1):

I think these are the steps you need:

1. use `scipy.misc.toimage` to convert your array to a PIL image
2. check out the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610159/convert-pil-image-to-cairo-imagesurface) to convert your PIL image to a cairo surface
3. use `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface` to convert this to a pixbuf (I don't know it's name in the python api)
4. make a Gtk.Image out of this using `Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf`

I'm sorry it needs so many conversion steps.

Comment: You could probably make something better by writing a function to convert your array to a Cairo texture. It would probably involve a lot more effort, but hundreds of people would thank you ;-)

Comment: Yes, I read a lot about Cairo textures but I've never actually used them.